# Using neural networks for portfolio selection

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, portfolio, control-theory

I'm currently trying to build an algorithm to maximize terminal wealth of a portfolio. I am using the REINFORCE with baseline algorithm present in Sutton and Barto (2018). I have one neural network for the policy, which has current wealth and time left on investment horizon as inputs, and outputs two values: a mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution. The discounted dollar amount invested in the risky asset is then sampled from this distribution. I have another network for the value function (same inputs but outputs state value). I have solved the problem analytically and my value network converges to the optimal solution well. My policy network does not which leads me to believe that I could improve the architecture of the network to 'help' it find the optimal solution. I am reasonably new to pytorch and neural networks and so would appreciate ideas as to how i could do this. My policy network is below, it has two hidden layers with 32 nodes each. I have also played around with the learning rates and it does not seem to help too much. Thanks!

```
class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    ''' Neural Network for the policy, which is taken to be normally distributed hence
    this network returns a mean and variance '''
    def __init__(self, lr, input_dims, fc1_dims, fc2_dims, n_returns):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.input_dims = input_dims
        self.fc1_dims = fc1_dims
        self.fc2_dims = fc2_dims
        self.n_returns = n_returns
        self.lr = lr
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(*self.input_dims, self.fc1_dims) # inputs should be wealth and time to maturity
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(self.fc1_dims,self.fc2_dims)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(self.fc2_dims,n_returns) # returns mean and sd of normal dist
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr = lr)
        
    def forward(self, observation):
        state = torch.Tensor(observation).float().unsqueeze(0)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        first_slice = x[:,0]
        second_slice = x[:,1]
        tuple_of_activated_parts = (
                first_slice, # let mean be negative
                #F.relu(first_slice), # make sure mean is positive
                #torch.sigmoid(second_slice) # make sure sd is positive
                F.softplus(second_slice) # make sd positive but dont trap below 1
                )
        out = torch.cat(tuple_of_activated_parts, dim=-1)
        return out
```

Comment: Typically in RL policy network and value network have the same structure, and their weights are regularly updated. Your PN looks OK, but the trick with `tuple_of_activated_parts` is not clear without context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The trick with the tuple is to ensure that the first output (mean) is linear and can be negative, the second output is the standard deviation so I applied a soft max activation function to it is above zero.